# Haskell Snap: mongodb field type error

Tags: mongodb, haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I get an error which I can't resolve.
The snap application compiles without a problem and everything seems to be ok.
But when I render the relevant page in a browser I get this error:

A web handler threw an exception. Details:
expected ("code" :: Integer) in [ _id: 50b56f19208c2e9a09dccc2b, id: 1.0, code: "hdg435", name: "froggy"]

The code value is just a rendom string I picked for testing. I am not sure why an integer is expected?

These are the relevant parts of an example snap application.

```
getData :: IO [Document]
getData = do
  pipe <- runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1"
  let run act = access pipe master "test" act
  result <- run (find (select [] "pcs") >>= rest)
  close pipe
  return $ either (const []) id result

mkSplice :: Document -> Splice AppHandler
mkSplice d = runChildrenWithText [dtp "id" d
                                 ,dtp "code" d
                                 ,dtp "name" d
                                 ]


dtp :: Text -> Document -> (Text,Text)
dtp tag d = (tag, T.pack $ show $ at tag d)

recSplice :: Splice AppHandler
recSplice = mapSplices mkSplice =<< liftIO getData

table :: Handler App App ()
table = heistLocal (bindSplice "rec" recSplice) $ render "table"
```

The relevant Heist template part of table.tpl is here:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <rec>
      <tr><td><id/></td><td><code/></td><td><name/></td></tr>
    </rec>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please let me know what other parts of code need to be posted.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would coerce that field to Integer.  The problem has to be somewhere else.  Perhaps the code that is actually being executed is not what you expect?  Perhaps you could try changing the code field to be an int and see what happens.  Also, my memory is that mongo is mostly schemaless, but could there be anything in mongo that that is expecting an Integer?

Comment: @mightybyte, thanks. I thought I was doing something dumb. This is really weird and I can't understand why. I changed the record so it contains just strings without any numbers like this: [ _id: 50b6e74852a4923015a9f225, id: "a", code: "hfgarqe", name: "froggy"] Still, it complains about expected integer. I am poling my hair now. Processing the above record I get this error: A web handler threw an exception. Details: expected ("id" :: Integer) in [ _id: 50b6e74852a4923015a9f225, id: "a", code: "hfgarqe", name: "froggy"] Maybe I should explicitly cast mongo values to haskell values ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile your dtp function I get:

```
import Data.Bson
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

dtp :: Text -> Document -> (Text,Text)
dtp tag d = (tag, T.pack $ show $ at tag d)

Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Show a0)
  [...]
```

which makes perfect sense.  It seems like in your case it's defaulting to Integer when you really want String.  You can try adding a signature or better yet, just:

```
dtp tag d = (tag, at tag d)
```

If you want this to work for other types, you'll have to work harder.

**UPDATE**

Here's a GHCi session that illustrates the problem and how GHCi seems to default the Show instance to Integer:

```
Prelude Data.Bson> show $ at "hello" ["hello" =: "world"]
"*** Exception: expected ("hello" :: Integer) in [ hello: "world"]
```

Comment: thank you very much. I actually just figured it out as well and forgot to update my question. I removed the show and everything went well. I don't understand why it defaults to integer though. But you are right, I have to work harder to convert all other possible data types. It was just  an initial test with mongo...